# Service stops updating location

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I am working on a app that has to work in the background and send location updates to the server.

The code is pretty simple and normaly works. There is a service that has a Timer that sends updates to the server every 15 seconds and it also implements the LocationListener Interface.

I dont think giving all the code would be useful, here is how I set up the class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER            , 5000, 10.0f, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER , 5000, 10.0f, this);

    //Ping Task sends updates to the Server
    Ping_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Ping_Task(), 5000, Ping_Task.TIME_GET_JOBS*1000 );
}
```

In practice I have some problems with my code. Services should work in the background, even if the Service stoppes there is a GCM system in place to restart the service in the background.

Even with these protections I still have the problems, sometimes the app does not update the location anymore, even if it is clear that the service is still running. On the Google Maps App I can see that the Location is correct there, but not in my app. How can this be, why do I not get the 'onLocationChanged' event anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First, I am not sure about `Service` life cycle. But I used the code below in `onStart()` method of the `Service`. This method is called after calling `startService(Intent)` method on `Context`. I guess, you can do this in `onCreate()` method.

Implement a location listener:

```
private final static LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //locationHandler will be created below.
        Message.obtain(locationHandler, 0, location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude()).sendToTarget();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

Give your listener to the method instead `this`

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10.0f, listener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10.0f, listener);
```

Implement a handler for this listener in your `onStart()` method in `Service`.

```
Handler locationHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        String location = (String) msg.obj;

        //do what you wanna do with this location

    }
}
```

This is how I did.

Comment: Why would I pass around a android.os.Message? I could just do what I do directly within the LocationListener.

Comment: Your choice, yes, you can directly call a method. But I needed a handler in my project.

Comment: One more thing, you say your locationManager to inform you about updates when 5 seconds passed "AND" 10 meter distance difference occurred. These 2 conditions must appear together to be able to get location updates. Here is a detailed explanation about this:
http://bit.ly/183woXY